# JaCoCo SonarQube incompatible version 1007

Tags: sonarqube, jacoco

I'm using SonarQube for code quality control and suddenly builds that would otherwise pass can't be analyzed and fails.

> [INFO] [00:00:03.630] Analysing /mySuperProject/target/jacoco.exec ->
>   java.io.IOException: Incompatible version 1007

When I invoke maven build with debug switch, this cause is revealed

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Incompatible version 1007.
at org.jacoco.core.data.ExecutionDataReader.readHeader(ExecutionDataReader.java:127)
at org.jacoco.core.data.ExecutionDataReader.readBlock(ExecutionDataReader.java:107)
at org.jacoco.core.data.ExecutionDataReader.read(ExecutionDataReader.java:87)
at org.sonar.plugins.jacoco.AbstractAnalyzer.readExecutionData(AbstractAnalyzer.java:134)
at org.sonar.plugins.jacoco.AbstractAnalyzer.analyse(AbstractAnalyzer.java:107)
```

While inspecting jacoco ExecutionDataReader, I found that exception is thrown from

```java
if (version != ExecutionDataWriter.FORMAT_VERSION) {
    throw new IOException(format("Incompatible version %x.",Integer.valueOf(version)));
}
```

and from ExecutionDataWriter I've found out

```java
/** File format version, will be incremented for each incompatible change. */
public static final char FORMAT_VERSION = 0x1007;
```

What is this **incompatible change** and why does it happen?
Any ideas how to fix this challenge?

Comment: Issue has been raised on SonarQube java plugin side : http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARJAVA-1091 and should be fixed in next release. This is a breaking change on JaCoCo side. Let us a little time to be able to fix it.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

As already mentioned, this is due to a break in JaCoCo maven plugin code.
You can (temporarily) specify the version in your jenkins maven command like:

```
clean org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:<version>:prepare-agent install
```

e.g.

```
clean org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.4.201502262128:prepare-agent install
```

This was the workaround that helped us. But like most people, I'm still waiting for the fix to come.

Comment: Nice trick, in environment with many subprojects that was cleanest solution so far

Comment: This is fixed in the latest version of the SonarQube Java PlugIn

Comment: I'm still getting this error with SonarQube 5.1.1.  How to force the latest SonarQube Java Plugin?

Comment: Had to update the Java Plugin within my SonarQube instance <SONAR_URL>/updatecenter/updates

Answer (score 32):

What I did was to specify the jacoco version in my maven project.

```
<jacoco-maven-plugin.version>0.7.4.201502262128</jacoco-maven-plugin.version>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${jacoco-maven-plugin.version}</version>
    </plugin>
```

That fix my issue!

Answer (score 17):

Most likely that's caused by latest jacoco-maven-plugin update. Everything was working on 0.7.4.201502262128 but today we switched to 0.7.5.201505241946 which resulted in this error.

Comment: I am seeing this as well. Do you have any more information on this?

Answer (score 6):

Run:

```
mvn clean org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent install
mvn org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent clean install -Pcoverage-per-test
mvn sonar:sonar
```

This will re-generate `.exec` files created by older versions of jacoco.

Answer (score 6):

Try to update the Java plugin in SonarQube Update Center, this works for me. I updated the Java plugin from version 2.4 to latest 3.13.1.

SonarQube Update Center -> Plugin Updates -> Java

Answer (score 2):

As kdowbecki mentionned it, this error is most likely due to an update of jacoco-maven-plugin.

Your SonarQube is most likely now using the new version of Jacoco Maven Plugin (probably the new 0.7.5.201505241946) but is actually trying to read an old version of a jacoco.exec (in your case it might be reading a jacoco.exec generated by jacoco maven plugin version 0.7.4.201502262128) which results in an incompatibility thrown by JaCoCo.

To fix this problem, you should make sure all your SonarQube/Jenkins jobs generate a JaCoCo report each time and do not rely on an older version of jacoco.exec that might have been generated by a previous job.

Answer (score 0):

For me this, when doing a `mvn install`

`Error while creating report: Cannot read execution data version 0x1006. This version of JaCoCo uses execution data version 0x1007`

meant I had done an archetype generate but the archetype accidentally included the target directory with old jacoco files in it (or it had been checked into git on accident).  Doing a mvn clean first (and checking that in) cleared up the issue.  Guess jacoco is reluctant to overwrite the jacoco.exec file with a new one when there are no unit tests to run or something like that, so the old file gets preserved and attempted to used for the jacoco report.  FWIW...

In general it means a [version mismatch](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jacoco/-j6hHiI9IwM) of generator vs. reporter.

Answer (score 0):

I changed pom.xml like

```
groupId=org.jacoco
artifactId=jacoco-maven-plugin
version=0.8.4-SNAPSHOT
```

it worked for me