# Incompatible version 1007 with sonarqube-maven-plugin 2.7.1 and jacoco-maven-plugin 0.7.5

Tags: sonarqube, jacoco-maven-plugin

The problem discussed in 
[JaCoCo SonarQube incompatible version 1007](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30459260/jacoco-sonarqube-incompatible-version-1007?s=1|3.0947)
is happening again with `sonarqube-maven-plugin 2.7.1`  in combination with `jacoco-maven-plugin 0.7.5.201505241946`

Executing `sonar:sonar` results in

```
java.io.IOException: Incompatible version 1007.
```

According to https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-1091 this should be fixed already.

The java plugin in my SQ-Server installation is version 3.3.

Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: Which version of the sonar java plugin (the version of the java plugin on your server installation) are you using ? please note this is not the same thing as the sonarqube maven plugin.

Comment: The java plugin in my SQ-Server installation is version 3.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are encoutering comes from a binary incompatiblity due to latest version of JaCoCo binary report. This issue has been fixed in version 3.4 of the sonar-java-plugin : https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-1091

Please update your plugin version, it should solve the issue.