# What version of Jacoco should I be using with gradle / sonarqube?

Tags: gradle, sonarqube, jacoco

So I have:

```
plugins {
...
    id "org.sonarqube" version "2.0"
    id "jacoco"
}
```

and also...

```
jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.7.1.201405082137"
}
```

and I'm getting...

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Incompatible version 1007.
```

Does this mean I have the wrong `toolVersion` and if so, what is the correct setting?

The server version I am targeting is 5.3.

Comment: http://www.lmdfdg.com/?q=jacoco+sonarqube+incompatible+version+1007&l=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JaCoCo SonarQube incompatible version 1007](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30459260/jacoco-sonarqube-incompatible-version-1007)

Answer (score 0):

We also had a hard time to find a version of JaCoCo compatible with all the toolchain. We found that version 0.7.5.201505241946 is working fine.

Comment: Well it doesn't seem to be working for me. ...or is there another issue that might cause the same error?

Comment: The answer of the referenced question (see question comment) helped me.