# which versions of gradle, sonarqube and jacoco plugins are compatible

Tags: gradle, sonarqube, jacoco, sonarqube-scan

I am setting up a new multi-module gradle project to be built in jenkins and trying to get sonarqube analysing it but I have struck several incompatibility issues which I haven't been able to resolve.

I am looking at using

1. the sonarqube plugin because our existing projects get a warning about the deprecation of sonar-runner:
   The 'sonar-runner' plugin has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 3.0. please use the official plugin from SonarQube ([the docs](https://redirect.sonarsource.com/doc/gradle.html)).
2. gradle 3
3. this simple example from sonarqube https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/blob/master/projects/languages/java/gradle/java-gradle-simple/build.gradle

If I use gradle 3 I get this error: org.gradle.internal.jvm.Jvm.getRuntimeJar()Ljava/io/File;

If I use gradle 2.14 I get this error:
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Incompatible version 1007
This error in the past has been caused by an incompatibility between the jacoco and sonarqube plugins see [JaCoCo SonarQube incompatible version 1007](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30459260/jacoco-sonarqube-incompatible-version-1007).

Which versions should I use?

Comment: Did you find a fix for this? I am facing the same issue

Comment: @BigDong ,stephen, any updates about compatible

 versions?

Answer (score 2):

FYI the release the SonarQube Scanner for Gradle 2.1 should happen very quickly and this version includes the support of Gradle 3.X. See https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARGRADL-16 which is already fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You are not alone. I get the same issues as well. This works with gradle 2.12.

```
plugins {
    id 'jacoco'
    id 'java'
    id "org.sonarqube" version "2.0.1"
}
```

Comment: I have tried with gradle 2.12 but still get the error 
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Incompatible version 1007.
....
$ ./gradlew -version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 2.12