# SonarQube no longer reporting test coverage from jacoco

Tags: sonarqube, jacoco-maven-plugin

SonarQube does no longer show test coverage for my project which is analyzed with jacoco. It seems there was an update on SonarQube (I found new rules dates May 19). I assume it also since then that the test coverage gathered with jacoco maven plugin is no longer evaluated. I've seen older questions with a similar issue, but that was 4 years ago:
[JaCoCo SonarQube incompatible version 1007](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30459260/jacoco-sonarqube-incompatible-version-1007)

I updated my POM to the latest plugin version 0.8.4 but to no avail. Any ideas where I need to change something so this works again?

Comment: Are you using SonarCloud? Which SonarQube version?

Comment: @JeroenHeier No, it's self hosted, we are using Version 6.7.1 (build 35068)

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. The problem was that [they deprecated the jacoco.exec](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/MMF-1651) file and now you have to use the XML format.

To use the new format you only have to install the **official jacoco plugin** in Sonarqube and everything it's going to work again without any more changes.